# Elasticsearch - different response for same query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have different response from apparently same query but in different format. This command show correct results

```
curl -XGET 'http://1.1.1.1:9200/myindex-*/api/_search?q=name:foo'
```

In this format I have different result:

```
curl -XGET 'http://1.1.1.1:9200/myindex-*/api/_search?pretty -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match": { "name": "foo" }
  }
}'
```

The last query returns more hits than those required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not the same queries.
The equivalent query for

```
curl -XGET 'http://1.1.1.1:9200/myindex-*/api/_search?q=name:foo'
```

is a `query_string` query, not a `match` query

```
curl -XPOST 'http://1.1.1.1:9200/myindex-*/api/_search?pretty -d'
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": { "query": "name:foo" }
  }
}'
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I sincerely doubt it. Make sure to send the second query via  POST. Maybe can you show a document that is returned in the second query but not the first?

Comment: Ok, great it helped!